# How to discover headless service endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to discover all the endpoints of a headless service from outside the cluster?

Preferably using DNS or Static IPs

Answer (score 5):

By [watching changes](http://kubernetes.io/third_party/swagger-ui/#!/api%2Fv1/watchNamespacedEndpointsList) to a list of Endpoints:

```
GET /api/v1/watch/namespaces/{namespace}/endpoints
```

Comment: Not optimal, can't use it in nginx for example. Any DNS options?

Comment: @shaylevi2 Is it possible to clarify how you can't use it in nginx?

Comment: Nginx expects a list of servers in the conf file, you can also use DNS A record, but you can't use a watching changes URL :\

Answer (score 4):

Headless Services are a group of Pod IPs.  Pod IPs are not (generally) available outside the cluster/cloud-provider.

Are you trying to get external IPs for a headless service or are you within the same network (e.g. in the GCE project) but not in the cluster?

Comment: Tim, if we were within the same network eg. in the GCE project, how would that change things? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I followed the steps here: http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets.html to create a MongoDB replica inside a GKE / cluster which works but we also want to access it from the project (instances that have apps installed until we move them). It's nice if we don't use the IP though and reference the cluster by hostnames like it's mentioned in the post (eg. mongo-1.mongo) or something that always points to the pod.

Comment: I'm GCE any VM can access the pod IPs.  Service IPs need a static route to one or more nodes

Answer (score 2):

The DNS addon is exactly what you're after. From the docs:

> For example, if you have a Service called "my-service" in Kubernetes
>   Namespace "my-ns" a DNS record for "my-service.my-ns" is created. Pods
>   which exist in the "my-ns" Namespace should be able to find it by
>   simply doing a name lookup for "my-service". Pods which exist in other
>   Namespaces must qualify the name as "my-service.my-ns". The result of
>   these name lookups is the cluster IP.

And in the case of a headless service:

> DNS is configured to return multiple A records (addresses) for the
>   Service name, which point directly to the Pods backing the Service.

However, this service is only available inside the cluster. But KubeDNS is just another pod:

```
kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system
kubectl describe po kube-dns-pod-name --namespace=kube-system
```

Which means you can create a service with an externally accessible address to expose this service. Just use a selector matching your kube-dns pod label.

http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/services.html#dns
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/cluster/addons/dns/README.md

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work for me, did you try it and it worked for you?

Comment: Yes, I'm successfully using the DNS addon inside my cluster, but I haven't tested using the DNS Service idea.

Comment: Inside the cluster it works, but I tried exposing the service and using it outside the cluster and for some reason it doesn't work.